# I'm trying to make a comparison with a date in my bdd mo

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, request, backend

I'm french beginner developper. My problem :

- I have a mongo database
- I am making queries to this database in python
- I run my python code with node to then make the link react with my front

I need to compare dates in my database to retrieve data based on dates.

problem when I compare the dice in the db with a date that I inserted in my comparison query, mongo returns an empty array, it's apparently a format problem, yet I tried a lot of stuff with the cat GPT. ..

my server.js code :
server.js execute index.js

```
const { searchData } = require('./index.js');
const moment = require('moment');

const fakeReq = {
  query: {
    date: '2023-11-30T00:00:00.000+00:00',
  },
};

const fakeRes = {
  status: (code) => ({
    json: (data) => console.log(`Response code: ${code}, data: `, data),
  }),
};

const fakeNext = () => {};

searchData(fakeReq, fakeRes, fakeNext);
```

==============================================================
my index.js code :
index.js execute test.py

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const moment = require('moment');

exports.searchData = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { date } = req.query;
  console.log("Récupération de l'argument de la requête");
  try {
    const pythonFilePath = './test.py';

    // Convertir la date en timestamp
    const timestamp = moment(date).valueOf();

    // Créer le processus Python avec le timestamp passé en tant qu'argument
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python', [pythonFilePath, '--timestamp', timestamp]);

    let results = '';

    // Collecter les données renvoyées par le script Python
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      results += data.toString();
    });

    // Gérer les erreurs éventuelles
    pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`Erreur de sortie : ${data}`);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Erreur lors de l'exécution du fichier Python" });
    });

    // Attendre la fin de la sortie pour envoyer la réponse
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('end', () => {
      console.log("Pas d'erreur Python");
      console.log("Résultats : ", results);
      res.status(200).json({ results });
    });

    // Gérer les événements de fermeture et d'erreur du processus Python
    pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        console.error(`Une erreur s'est produite : ${code}`);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Erreur lors de l'exécution du fichier Python" });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Erreur lors de la recherche dans la base de données :', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur lors de la recherche dans la base de données' });
  }
};
```

==============================================================
my test.py code :
test.py execute request

```
import argparse
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

# Configuration de l'analyseur d'arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--timestamp', type=int, help='Le timestamp spécifié dans la requête')

# Analyse des arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# Récupération du timestamp
timestamp = args.timestamp

# Se connecter à la base de données MongoDB
client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://pierre:ztxiGZypi6BGDMSY@atlascluster.sbpp5xm.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

# Sélectionner la base de données
db = client.test

# Sélectionner la collection
collection = db.testDate

# Requête pour récupérer les documents avec le champ "date" inférieur au timestamp spécifié
query = {'date': {'$lt': timestamp}}

# Récupérer les documents
documents = collection.find(query)

# Convertir les documents en liste de dictionnaires JSON
json_data = [json.loads(json.dumps(document)) for document in documents]

# Afficher les données JSON
response_data = json.dumps(json_data)
print(response_data)
```